# junit - SOAP REQUEST - Cannot parse date

Tags: java, soap, junit, date-parsing

I am trying to execute a junit test on my deployed web service.But while passing the existing soap request as parameter to my deployed method I am getting the following error.

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot parse date 2016-12-09
```

I am using the following request.

```
<com.sampleclass>
<remark>TEST</remark>
<toDate>2016-12-09</toDate>
</com.sampleclass>
```

While my variable in the corresponding data class is.

```
private Date toDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems problem with you date format your passing. You have two ways to overcome this issue.

1. Set the date in a format what is the library supports default.
2. Register your own format

   `XStream xstream = new XStream();
   String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
   String[] acceptableFormats = {"yyyy-MM-dd"};
   xstream.registerConverter(new DateConverter(dateFormat, acceptableFormats));`

Thanks,

Irham

Comment: Well thanks Irham actually instead I have changed the format of date in soap request itself and it worked well.

Comment: E.g. 2016-12-19 18:30:00.0 UTC 11:29 AM